# CxCallAction for speaker button in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I want to make an app for an academic purpose.  When in a call between two persons one of them presses the speaker button the other person is informed by push notification or via sms that the speaker is ON or OFF.  Is that possible?  Do I have to make the call through voip app?  Is it possible via cellular?[image: thats only i found]

https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxcallaction